# Convergence of expectation of inverse sum of random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $X_1,..,X_n,...$ are positive random variables, such that $(X_1+...+X_n)/n\to\mu$ almost surely as $n\to\infty$.

I intuitively believe that $\mathbb{E}\Big[\frac{Y}{(X_1+...+X_n)/n}\Big]\to\mathbb{E}[Y]/\mu$ for any random variable $Y$, as the integrand converges to $Y/\mu$ almost surely.

Is this true? What convergence theorem can be used to prove this sort of proposition?

Answer (score 1):

<s>One way to prove this is to use [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem#Statement), which states that $\frac{Y}{(X_1+...+X_n)/n}$ converges in distribution to $Y/\mu$ provided that $\mu\neq 0$. This implies the property you stated.</s>

I suspect that this is false since almost sure convergence of $\left\{Z_n\right\}$ to a constant $\mu$ does not imply the convergence of $\mathbb{E}\left[Z_n\right]$ to $\mu$. Take for example $Z_n$ such that
$$P(Z_n=n^2)=1/n^2$$
$$P(Z_n=0)=1-1/n^2$$
Then $\left\{Z_n\right\}$ converges almost surely to $0$ since $\sum_nP(|Z_n-0|>\varepsilon)<\infty$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, but $\mathbb{E}\left[Z_n\right]=1$ does not converge to $0$.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful

Comment: What about when the random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent and identically distributed so that the denominator in the original post is the sample mean? The sample mean seems much more 'regular' than the counterexample you suggest. So is it possible the expectation converges in the case of the sample mean (which I imagine is what the originally poster is primarily interested in)?